# How to disable screenshot or blur the content is iOS like ScreenShieldKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security

I know we can get `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` with  observer  `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification`. But this does not prevent the screenshot.

I want to build something like [ScreenShieldKit](https://screenshieldkit.com/) which blurs the content before taking screenshots . I have tested the BlackBox app which uses this SDK , I works even when we take screenshot from Xcode device and simulator . I want to know how they are managing to prevent this ?

Is is possible to make a custom uilable or uiimage and convert it to DRM video stream and show it on screen ?

Is there any private framework which can prevent this ?

I know people comment that someone can take recored or capture screen using other device ,I have separate process to prevent that also.

Answer (score 0):

Till now, There is no such way in IOS to prevent user from taking screenshot when application is running, and that's because you do not have access to delete photos in the photo gallery of the user. It would totally be a security issue if you could access your user's photos.

Yes, you can do that stuff in Android but not in iOS.

Comment: How to get notify before the iOS take screenshot and blur my content ? so that user only see the blur content in screenshot

Comment: You can see it in action. check [ScreenShieldKit](https://screenshieldkit.com/). I wonder how they did it

Comment: @LalKrishna is this Legal ?
I dont think so its legal. What you say ?

Comment: I don't think it's illegal. There must some way to do it. Also they wait for patent

Comment: I very curious to know how they are working .How they are managing to do that and uploading to to App Store ..?? Is there any private framework ?

Comment: We cannot take screenshort of DRM video , is there any way where we can convert a uitextlable content to DRM video stream

Answer (score -1):

Give it a try,

Use swift 4 and put breakpoint on

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
```

and on

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
```

Am currently busy with something but i also need to search solution so that i don't have to pay those screensheildkit guys.

If the resignActive delegate get called then just add an image on root and if not then wait for the solution.